# Using Drupal Rules to create a CiviCRM Contact - does not load entity ID

Tags: civicrm-entity, drupal-rules

I'm trying to create a new Civi Contact for a new Drupal user when added by admin.

I then want to copy over Drupal registration field values to the newly created CiviCRM contact.

I'm getting stuck at first base. I created a rule to create the CiviCRM Contact entity. That works fine.

Then I'm using the entity-created-id - the contact ID to populate the FK to Contact ID parameter required for making a linked email entity.

But it is not loading the entity-created-id no matter what recipe of rules I'm trying.

Comment: Would be good to understand why you are not using out of the box approach to creating contacts from a Drupal User creation. Drupal + Civi just 'does' this normally, and by adding a civicrm profile to the Drupal user registration you can then have civi fields used on the user create form. What is the reason for doing something custom?